# CSS sticky ignores 1px

Tags: html, css

I want to make a navbar that sticks to the top, but when it sticks there is a small gap. I have no margins or paddings.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topdiv"></div>
    <div class="bardiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
html, body {
    height: 200%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.topdiv {
    height: 50px;
}

.bardiv {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

It doesn't appear at all zoom levels, for example on jsfiddle I see it only at 175%.
That happens only if the topdiv has the height declared in pixels, also setting bardiv top: -1px solves it as well, but I don't understand why now it doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/daxy5mru/41/

Comment: Yours works well. I don't see a 1 pixel gap.

Comment: Certain zoom levels and elements positioned next to each other with sticky (or even absolute at times) can be an artifact of certain browsers.  Safari tends to be one of them.

Comment: I am using chrome and it only shows gap on 100% zoom, I would put `top: -1px` just to make sure it works in every zoom level.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can not simply use HTML & CSS, you should also use JavaScript to keep the header sticky on scroll.

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction();
};
// Get the navbar
var header = document.getElementById("Navbar");
// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;
// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position.
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the header */

.navbar {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #555;
}


/* Page content */

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}


/* The sticky class is added to the header with JS when it reaches its scroll position */

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent as the header gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <p>Logo</p>
</div>
<div class="navbar" id="Navbar">
  <h2>your navigation bar</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae
    voluptatibus.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That would ignore the first div, I don't want the nav bar to be at the top always

Comment: Hi @soborat according to your question you need your navbar to stick on top? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: topdiv is the logo, below there is the navbar which I want to stick to the top when the user scrolls down.

Comment: @soborat I have changed the code as you wanted above, The Idea is there is a class change on scroll, that cant be used using only HTML and CSS, so you need the javascript to change the css attribute. check the code and I have added comments. Hope this is what you were wishing for.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working and there is no pixel gap. But I still don't know why CSS position: sticky has that white line above. Anyway I will use your version for this nav because it integrates better with the rest of the code, thanks!

Comment: @soborat maybe that is because of some implementation issue, or the window scaling! Try to use best coding practices and while asking questions, explain what you doing and what you are expecting from it, also accept answers if your problem solved !, Happy coding 

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use "top: -1px".

Example class:

```
.table-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think using a negative value is a correct way, try always to avoid that kind of values

Comment: Do you know the reason why? Even Bootstrap uses negative margins. This is a simple solution to a common problem. It's what I'll be using in the future.

Comment: The reason I prefer it is that, unlike the accepted answer, it requires no JS.